# JAVA - Sockets :: readline() not doing anything

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, readline, serversocket

I created a Network-class where I open a socket an than send requests to it.

The class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Network implements Runnable {
    private boolean isHost = false;

    private int hostPort = 19250;
    private int clientPort = 19251;
    private String host = "127.0.0.1";
    private String name = "";

    private ServerSocket ownServer = null;
    private Socket otherServer = null;
    private DataOutputStream outToServer = null;
    private BufferedReader inFromServer = null;
    private boolean isConnected = false;

    /**
     * Konstruktor -
     */
    Network(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.findHost();
        // if no host exists, become host itself
        if (this.isHost == false) {
            // host da -> become client
            System.out.println(this.name + ": host found");
            try {
                ownServer = new ServerSocket(this.clientPort);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            // kein host da -> become host
            System.out.println(this.name + ": no host found");

            try {
                ownServer = new ServerSocket(this.hostPort);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * connect() - versucht mit anderem server zu connecten fals dies noch nicht
     * geschehen ist
     * 
     * @return true/false
     */
    public boolean connect() {

        if (this.isConnected == false) {
            try {
                if (this.isHost) {
                    otherServer = new Socket(this.host, this.clientPort);
                } else {
                    otherServer = new Socket(this.host, this.hostPort);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //System.out.println(this.name + ": connect failed");
                this.isConnected = false;
                return false;
            }
        }

        try {
            outToServer = new DataOutputStream(otherServer.getOutputStream());
            inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    otherServer.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //System.out.println(this.name + ": connect sucess");
        this.isConnected = true;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * findHost() - schaut ob ein Host existiert
     * 
     * @return true/false
     */
    private boolean findHost() {
        Socket hostSocket;
        try {
            hostSocket = new Socket(this.host, this.getHostPort());
            DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(
                    hostSocket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(hostSocket.getInputStream()));
            outToServer.writeBytes("uHost?\n");// Fragen ob Host ist
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.isHost = true;
            return false; // Keine Connection aufgebaut => kein Host vorhanden
        }
        this.isHost = false;
        return true; // Es gibt schon einen Host
    }

    public int getClientPort() {
        return this.clientPort;
    }

    public int getHostPort() {
        return this.hostPort;
    }

    public boolean getIsHost() {
        return this.isHost;
    }

    /**
     * sendToOther() - schickt daten an anderen Server
     * 
     * @param data
     */
    public void sendToOther(String data) {
        this.connect();
        try {
            this.outToServer.writeBytes(data);
            this.outToServer.writeBytes("\n"); //new Line
            this.outToServer.flush();
            System.out.println(this.name + ": " + data
                    + " :: send to other server");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            this.outToServer.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // listen to income
        String line = "";
        try {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println(this.name + ":111");
                while ((line = inFromServer.readLine())!= null) {
                    System.out.println(this.name + ":222");
                    System.out.println(this.name + ":recieved: " + line);
                }
                System.out.println(this.name + ":333");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void readAndDo(String data) {
        System.out.println(this.name + ": data recieved: " + data);
    }

}
```

The main Method:

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Network t1net=new Network("ss1");
        Network t2net=new Network("ss2");
        t1net.connect();
        t2net.connect();


        t1net.sendToOther("some text1");
        t2net.sendToOther("sometext2");



        Thread t1 = new Thread( t1net );
        t1.start();


        Thread t2 = new Thread( t2net );
        t2.start();
    }

}
```

the console:

```
ss1: no host found
ss2: host found
ss1: some text1 :: send to other server
ss2: sometext2 :: send to other server
ss2:111
ss1:111
```

netstat -a:

```
  TCP    127.0.0.1:19250        49on41PCX:54538        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:19250        49on41PCX:54540        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:19251        49on41PCX:54539        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49156        49on41PCX:0            ABHÖREN
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54538        49on41PCX:19250        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54539        49on41PCX:19251        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54540        49on41PCX:19250        HERGESTELLT
```

The problem is, that the Network.run() block in the readline()-command. The data is send, bu never recieved.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: It connects in the Network.connect() Method. Or isn't that what you mean?

Comment: You should start by separating out the client and the server, this is not very readable. I guess you are just missing a `flush` after you write the string on the client.

Comment: Seperating is not an option in this case. The flush is called in the Network.sendToOther() directly after writing the string.

Comment: @user3443137 no it isn't, you are declaring the `outToServer` variable locally in the `findHost` method. There is no way to flush that from the other method. Since you are Pokemon catching all exceptions, you don't see the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: The findHost() method doesnt do anything usefull in the connection. It is just used to find out if a host exists. The connection is not handled there. | Catching all Exeptions also include NullPointers, so there shouldnt be a problem with that

Comment: BTW Don't use DataInput/OutputStreams when writing text.  Just take them out as you don't need them. You might try to use them as DataStream and this is more likely to confuse you than be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You have used the sockets in a wrong manner.

ss : ServerSocket

s : Socket

You have first made two `ss` on two threads and made two `s` connecting to the the intial `ss`. In this way `ss1` is bound to `s2` and `ss2` is bound to `s1`. And you have implemented input and output only from `s1` and `s2`. So if you write from `s1`, it won't go into `s2`. In fact you need to create another socket from `ss2` that will accept connections. And the same with `ss1`. I hope you get my point

Actually you should have created only one `ss` for the host. Then:

> socketHost = ss.accept();
>
> socketClient = new Socket(host, port);

Now you can use these two sockets for communication with each other by using their I/O streams.

In short earlier you had made two connections say `a` and `b`. You sent and received from `a` on one thread and sent and received data from `b` on the second thread.

Just look up on some tutorial of simple socket I/O and you will understand.

**EDIT**: See EchoClient.java and EchoServer.java from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html